# Define antisymmetric matrix implicitly

Tags: matrix

I have to define three $6\times 6$ matrices that should be antisymmetric in the two indices.

What I have done is using the following command

```
$Assumptions = {M0 \[Element] 
    Matrices[{6, 6}, Reals, Antisymmetric[{1, 2}]], 
   M1 \[Element] Matrices[{6, 6}, Reals, Antisymmetric[{1, 2}]], 
   M2 \[Element] Matrices[{6, 6}, Reals, Antisymmetric[{1, 2}]]};
```

But when I try to do the following

```
M0[1, 2] + M0[2, 1] // Simplify
```

I do not get zero. I need the antisymmetric property to be reflected in the indices and not only on the whole matrix since when I do

```
Transpose[M0]+M0//Simplify
```

I do indeed get zero.

Comment: I can't run your code because `M0` is undefined for me

Comment: @IntroductionToProbability M0 has no specific form, is just a $6\times 6$ antisymmetric matrix

Comment: @Quiver, there are several problems. First of all, your second code (`Transpose[M0]+M0//Simplify`) doesn't seem to work. Perhaps you have defined `M0` somewhere, so try with `Clear[M0]` first, and then it should indeed not work. What does work is `Transpose[M0] + M0 // TensorReduce`. Secondly, matrix elements should be accessed with double square brackets, `M0[[2, 1]]`, not with single ones. However, this will not work either because you have to define `M0` first. You can do this, for example, with: `M0 = Normal@SymmetrizedArray[Table[m[i, j], {i, 6}, {j, 6}], {6, 6}, Antisymmetric[{1, 2}]]`

Comment: @Domen Yes, sorry I copied the wrong code, indeed there should not be a Simplify but a TensorReduce. I'll try the code you gave me, thank you!